# How to loop through different image crops?

Tags: python, opencv

So what I want to do is loop through two image crops and then see how many white pixels there are on both of these images. If a certain amount is detected on one image you print out something and if another amount is detected on the other you print out something etc etc.

I currently have this:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

#img = cv2.imread('FIFA_Full_Crop_2_button.jpg')
img = cv2.imread('FIFA2.jpg') 
#img = cv2.imread('FIFA_Full_Crop_2_button_3.jpg')

mask = np.zeros(img.shape[:2], np.uint8)

bgdModel = np.zeros((1, 65), np.float64)
fgdModel = np.zeros((1, 65), np.float64)

rect = (1512, 20, 180, 185) # boundary of interest
cv2.grabCut(img, mask, rect, bgdModel, fgdModel, 5, cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT)
mask2 = np.where((mask == 2) | (mask == 0), 0, 1).astype('uint8')
img = img * mask2[:, :, np.newaxis]
cv2.imwrite('Image_mask.jpg', img)

mx = (1510, 22, 110, 185)
x, y, h, w = mx

# x,y coordinates for specified "fixed" location

# Left button 
# mx = (1525, 58, 27, 22)
# x, y, h, w = mx

# Circle button 2
# mz = (1664, 58, 27, 22)
# x, y, h, w = mz

# Output to files
crop = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
cv2.imwrite('Image_crop.jpg', crop)

cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
cv2.imwrite('Image_cont.jpg', img)

# Detect white pixels from cropped image
img = cv2.imread('Image_crop.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,gray = cv2.threshold(gray, 150,255,0)
gray2 = gray.copy()

cv2.imshow('IMG',gray2)

# Example left button detection 72 pixels
# n_white_pix = np.sum(gray2 == 255)
# print('Number of white pixels:', n_white_pix)
# if crop.sum() >= 72:
#     print("Left")
# else:
#     print("No button detected")

n_white_pix = np.sum(gray2 == 255)
print('Number of white pixels:', n_white_pix)
if n_white_pix > 0:
    print("White pixel detected")
else:
    print("Nothing detected")

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

As seen above I have commented out the left button and circle part as I can only do one image crop at a time, how would I go about in doing things if I want to check both crops at the same time?

An ideal solution would be looping through the button crops and then checking them with `n_white_pix` to see if they exceed a certain amount.

So the main problem at hand now is, how do I loop through two image crops, `# Left button` and `# Circle button 2`.

Comment: you can use `and`/`or`/`not` in `if`/`elif` - like `if crop.sum() >= 72 and n_white_pix >= 90: print("left, Circle")`

Comment: if *that* is indeed the answer, I'm inclined to change the title to "*how to use boolean logic in python*"

Comment: why do you imwrite a file and then imread the same file again? you already know that `cvtColor` exists

Comment: Ah that's a fault on my end was still fiddling around with the imgwrites to see differences. And no that's not the answer the problem I'm running into is not being able to check two crops at the same time. I'll be editing this later today to a more sophisticated question @ChristophRackwitz